# Is there a solution for generating a JSON SMD for a Spring 3 REST Controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest, dojo, smd

A colleague and I are setting up an architecture for rapid development of rich client-side apps using REST and JSON.  Our server is using Spring 3's MVC and REST features to expose REST services as Spring controllers.  For non-standard REST calls, we'd like to use Service Mapping Descriptors (SMD) to expose the contract of certain controllers:

http://groups.google.com/group/json-schema/web/service-mapping-description-proposal

SMD looks fairly new on the scene; is there any solution out there right now for generating an SMD JSON file from a Spring 3 REST controller?

Comment: What is a non-standard REST call?

Comment: I suppose more of an RPC style url, such as putting a verb into the URL instead of a noun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own HttpMessageConverter:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="my.package.CustomJsonHttpConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

where CustomJsonHttpConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter, just like the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.

Comment: This is the standard approach.  I was mostly curious if there was any existing implementations out there.  Good opportunity for me to contribute something to the open source world.